# Virtualize ESXi 6.7 under ESXi 6.0

Tags: vmware, virtualization, esxi

Good day
Is it possible to virtualize ESXi 6.7 in an existing ESXi 6.0?

The reason for this is to do tests before upgrading the main ESXi 6.0.

Main:
hpe-DL380 --- ESXi 6.0 --- vCenter6.0-vm

Want to test:
hpe-DL380 --- ESXi 6.0 --- nested ESXi 6.7

Found these nested ESX packages from here.
https://williamlam.com/nested-virtualization/nested-esxi-virtual-appliance

Thank you.

Comment: I googled "esxi inside esxi" and found some positive results. My guess is that it's ok for testing, but not as a production environment. I personally never did it, but would be interested to know how it works out. Perhaps if you do it, you could post the answer to your own question here so the community can see the result.

Answer (score 1):

You may be in luck due to using 6.0 but you will need a very specific configuration and this procedure is completely bleeding edge and totally unsupported.  Furthermore it's been a few years since I worked at VMware and I don't have access to an ESXi host so the commands may have some minor typos.

0. get to the ESXi command line (https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-12E27BF3-3769-4665-8769-DA76C2BC9FFE.html) and list the USB drivers manually using "vmkload_mod -l".  If you see "usb-storage" you are in luck.  If you see "vmkusb" then you're out of luck and can stop here (see below for why).
1. configure your ESXi 6.0 host to have no requirement for USB storage.  For example, if your host boots from an SD card attached to the motherboard via a USB SD card reader then you need to get another host.
2. backup all your data or migrate the VMs you care about or whatever.
3. run these 3 commands (typos are possible)

- service usb-arbitrator stop
- vmkload_mod -u usb-storage
- service usb-arbitrator start

You will have to repeat this after every reboot but you can make it permanent with this procedure: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2147565.

4. download a bootable ISO image of ESXi 6.7 from, for example, https://customerconnect.vmware.com/downloads/details?productId=742&downloadGroup=ESXI670
5. burn the ISO image to a USB flash drive using, for example, https://miketabor.com/create-bootable-esxi-installer-usb-flash-drive/
6. attach the USB flash drive to your host and pass it through to your VM when your VM is powered off.
7. boot your VM from the ISO image on the USB flash drive and install the desired version of ESXi.
8. With newer versions of ESXi (6.7, 7.0) on the host this is no longer possible because the vmkusb native driver is monolithic so when the storage functionality is unloaded the host controller functionality also goes away.

Answer (score 0):

So, today, i downloaded this file, Nested_ESXi6.7_Appliance_Template_v1.ova and tried to deployed it in the ESXi 6.0.

The result is a failure.
vSphere client complained about the unsupported hardware family, vmx-13.

Looks like the nested ESXi version must be at least the same version as the physical ESXi.

[image: deploying the ova]

Comment: It means that the OVA you obtained was exported from a VM created with minimum required ESX version set higher than 6.0. I don't think this the absolute minimum capable of running ESXi. I'd suggest trying to install ESXi 6.7 on a manually-created VM on the 6.0 ESXi to see if it works (adding the necessary advanced options of course).